# C++ Program not creating output file. Compiler shows no errors

Tags: c++

My program is not creating the output file to display the organize array. The code runs without errors but upon checking the folder holding the source file I do not see a file called result.txt. Any ideas why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void sort(double a[], int control);
int main()
{
    int control=15;
    double a[control];
    ifstream in_stream;
    in_stream.open("data.txt");
    if(in_stream.fail())
    {
    cout<<"Input file opening failed\n.";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        in_stream>>a[i];
    }
    in_stream.close();

    sort(a,control);

    ofstream out_stream;
    out_stream.open("result.txt");
    if(out_stream.fail())
        {
            cout<<"Output file opening failed\n.";
            exit(1);
        }
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        out_stream<<a[i];
    }
    out_stream.close();

    return 0;
}

void sort(double a[], int control)
{
    int swapped=0,temp,i;
    while(1)
    {
    for (i=0;i<control;i++)
        {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=temp;
            swapped=1;
        }
        if (swapped == 0)break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe it did not find your input file and exited after printing "Input file opening failed"

Comment: You're using [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is technically not part of C++. Make `control` a compile-time constant, and I recommend using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain C-style arrays.

Comment: As for *one* of your problem, in the `sort` function you *go out of bounds* which of course leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Your logic also seems *very* flawed. Lastly I recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Start MUCH smaller. Focus on simply creating a file called result.txt in a folder. Once you've achieved that, focus on writing a single number to that file. From there, you can move up to creating many numbers to store into the file. Don't just write 50 lines, hit compile and wonder why it didn't work properly.

Comment: Also learn how to use your debugger. If you single stepped through the program (looking at the relevant variables at each step)  you would have likely already solved this or had a different question on why it was behaving differently than you expected.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll check out the links posted and start small.

Comment: `int control=15;
    double a[control];` wait should that even be compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Your program never reaches the part where you write down the output stream because it gets stuck in infinite loop inside your sort method.

You can use this bubble sort method.

```
// A function to implement bubble sort
void sort(double a[], int control) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < control - 1; i++)

        // Last i elements are already in place
        for (j = 0; j < control - i - 1; j++)
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
            }
}
```